# Writing commonjs module and load it using require (not using relative path)

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

What is best pratice for referencing a local commonjs module without using a relative path as below?

```
var custMod= require(‘customModule’);
custMod(true);
custMod.save(‘foo’);
```

Is there any reference for building a module like this?

If I wrote module like below, getting undefined when I call custMode.save(12);

```
module.exports = customModule;function customModule(mode) {
  var mode = 1;
  return {
    save: function (value) {
        console.log(mode, value)
    },
    get: function (id) {
        console.log(mode, id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a module that injects global variables? Or how to create a function that also has custom properties? What exactly is the "this" you are talking about?

Comment: [writing modular js](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)

Comment: @FelixKling I was asking about writing module  that injects global variables and can be loaded using require function.

Comment: Still not 100% sure what you're asking for, but I've added an answer based on my assumptions. What do you mean by "injects global variables"?

Comment: Every module can be loaded with `require`. Injecting global variables should be avoided. How the module can be loaded (i.e. via a direct path or just the name) cannot be influenced by the module itself. It depends on how the Node environment is set up. This may help to understand the issue: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: I would advise thinking more carefully about what `custMod` is. Does it have a `save` property? If it doesn't, how would you get the object that has `save`? Try it in the node console.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a path for `require` to check using

```
require.paths.push('/my/path');
```

or

```
require.main.paths.push('/my/path');
```

Depending on your node version.

Then if `customModule.js` exists at `/my/path/customModule.js`, you can just use

```
require('customModule');
```

Do note though, you'd need to do this on every module that you intend to use this method on.

Comment: *"Otherwise, you're going to need to npm link or add your module to NPM."* Not really. All that really is required is that the module is located in the package's `node_modules` folder. `npm` just makes this more convenient. But yeah, adding to npm became a bit more practical, now that it offers private modules.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, removed. I don't think that is what I was looking for, but I could've sworn there was an NPM-cli flag that would copy a folder into `node_modules`.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what npm link would do (it links a module into the current package). I was just saying that you don't *need* it (I guess I'm too picky ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I wish node made this easier to be honest. One possibility:

```
project_root
`--node_modules
   |--npm-module-1
   |--npm-module-2
   |--... (etc)
   `--lib
      |--my-module.js
      `--my-other-module.js
```

With the above you can then type `require('lib/my-module')` from anywhere in your project. (Just make sure and never install an npm module named `lib` :) Another possibility:

```
project_root
|--node_modules
|  |--npm-module-1
|  |--npm-module-2
|  `--... (etc)
`--lib
   `--node_modules
      |--my-module.js
      `--my-other-module.js
```

With the above you can then type `require('my-module')`, but only for any files under `project_root/lib/`.

An advantage of the former approach is that `require('lib/my-module')` makes it super easy at a glance to tell which modules are local to the project. However the latter is less typing.